# why pointer is more efficient than array in use

Tags: c

why pointer is more efficient or superior than declaring array?

Comment: are you just posting questions from homework as they appear on your list? (btw I don't downvote)

Comment: Alright, I helped you on your last question but you should probably slow down now. 3 questions in half an hour is probably too many. If these are questions on a homework assignment, refer to your textbook or ask your professor. (That said, I hope such isn't being asked anywhere, because it's fairly meaningless.)

Comment: and not a single accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing apples to oranges.

A pointer holds a value which is the address of another variable. An array is a contiguous collection of items. They aren't the same.

If you clarify your question, we could give you a better answer. As it stands, it's pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't. According to the C standard, `a[x]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+x)`.
In fact, modern processors can produce sometimes faster code if `a[x]` is used instead of raw pointer arithmetic as some static analyses can compute more information in this case, enabling more aggressive optimizations. The reason is the easier alias analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing (a few years back) I found the exact opposite - an array reference was faster than a pointer.  I think this was with MSVC 6.0. It all depends on the assembly code the compiler decides to generate, and it's quite arbitrary.

To clarify, I was comparing something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < length;  ++i)
    sum += p[i];

for (int i = 0;  i < length;  ++i)
    sum += *p++;
```